# Additive power series in positive characteristic

Tags: commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

Let $K$ be a field of positive characteristic $p$. Consider a power series $F\in K[[X_1,\dots,X_n]]$ that is additive, that is, $$F(X_1+Y_1,\dots,X_n+Y_n)=F(X_1,\dots,X_n)+F(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)\in K[[X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_n]].$$ Is it true that there exists $n$ additive power series $F_1,\dots,F_n$ ($F_i\in K[[X_i]]$) such that $F(X_1,\dots,X_n)=F_1(X_1)+\dots+F_n(X_n)$?

Comment: Have you tried considering cases for the degree of F? I am not sure if this is the right approach but that is my inclination (other than possibly messing around with algebra-finite K-vector spaces).

Comment: Applying additivity enough times and you have $F(X_1,\dots,X_n)=F(X_1,0,\dots,0)+F(0,X_2,0,\dots,0)+\dots+F(0,\dots,0,X_n)$.

Comment: I think you’re asking whether an additive power series necessarily has all its monomials “pure”, that is, each involving only one variable. Why don’t you look for an impure monomial that’s additive? This wouldn’t dispose of the question, but at least it would give you some insight.